# Delphi - How to consume a WCF Service with netHTTPBindings

Tags: wcf, delphi, binding, delphi-xe

I have a WCF Service written in Visual Studio 2015 (c#) that uses web sockets, this means the endpoint is configured with netHTTPBindings. I have a Delphi application that I have currently written in XE and would like to consume the WCF Service, what is the best way for a Delphi application to consume a web socket WCF Service?

// Edit ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am now using wsDualHttpBindings, here is some prototype code:

WCF Service interface

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IStatusCallback))]
public interface IStatusService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task StartSendingStatus();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IStatusCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task SendStatus(string aValue);
}
```

Implementation

```
public class StatusService : IStatusService
{
    public async Task StartSendingStatus()
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IStatusCallback>();
        while (((IChannel)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            await callback.SendStatus(GetStatus());
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    private string GetStatus()
    {
        // For now return datetime 
        string dt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        return Convert.ToString(dt);
    }
}
```

Here is how I consume it in a C# application, I put the result into list box.

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    private StatusServiceReference.StatusServiceClient StatusService;

    private class CallbackHandler : StatusServiceReference.IStatusServiceCallback
    {
        private ListBox _listbox;
        public CallbackHandler(ListBox aListBox)
        {
            _listbox = aListBox;
        }

        public void SendStatus(string aValue)
        {
            _listbox.Items.Add(aValue);
            _listbox.SelectedIndex = _listbox.Items.Count - 1;   
        }
    }

    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var context = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler(StatusListBox));
        StatusService = new StatusServiceReference.StatusServiceClient(context);
    }

    private void StatusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StatusService.StartSendingStatus();
    }
}
```

This works fine, I would like to know the best way to do the above client code in Delphi. When I import the WSDL file it does not have the IStatusServiceCallback interface.

Comment: netHTTPBindings is .NET only. Just open up the WCF for BasicHTTPBinding. If you can't do that, you could create a .NET COM DLL wrapper that talks with the WCF.

Comment: BasicHTTPBindings does not support duplex, which is required for the web socket. I will look at whether I can use wsDualHTTPBindings instead, my test c# console app works with wsDualHTTPBindings.

Comment: From what I have read callbacks using wsDualHTTPBinding only works with .NET, so it looks like this cannot be achieved using Delphi and I need another way.

Comment: Like I said, expose needed functionality via a COM DLL and use that from Delphi. It is really easy to consume the WS in .NET...

Comment: Yes I know it is easy to consume the WCF service in .NET, but my question was how to consume it in a Delphi application. It seems a limitation of Delphi that it cannot consume the service directly. Do you know of any examples or documents on the best practive on how to send updates to a Delphi application from a WCF service? Is one way to do a HTTP post to the Delphi application (HTTP server) from the service.

Comment: I've added some prototype code of the service and how I consume it in a C# application in the question.

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make, you can't implement netHTTPBindings  from **any** unmanaged environment (Delphi, Java, C++,...) except for .NET Itself...